# how can we convert spline points into polygon vertices or vice versa

Tags: geometry, unreal-engine5, blueprint, 3d-model, 3d-modelling

Is there is any way to convert spline point into polygon vertices or polygon vertices into spline.
I have blueprint in unreal engine 5 that is using spline point but my given input is in of polygon vertices.

The blueprint is complicated so i don't want to change it. So, I am finding a way to covert polygon vertices into spline points.